# Variable length array error with constexpr

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I have a class with a member function which declares an array whose size is based off a formula.

```
template <int SIZE>
class Example{
   constexpr int lookup(const int n) const
   {
      return n * n + n;
   }
   inline void func()
   {
       double array[lookup(SIZE)];
   }
};
```

This gives me the vla error. I think it should work because `SIZE` is resolved at compile time, and lookup is a `constexpr`. I know the following will work:

```
template <int SIZE>
class Example{

   inline void func()
   {
       constexpr int sz = SIZE * SIZE + SIZE;
       double array[sz];
   }
};
```

I guess I'm just trying to figure out why

**EDIT** Sorry for the typos, was trying to just write a smaller example and ended up with the missing `n` and class name.

Comment: Where is `n` coming from?

Comment: With a few small syntax fixes, it complies and runs fine: https://repl.it/repls/WanLavishComputergames

Comment: @BillLynch - compile and run fine but isn't standard C++; if you add "-pedantic", you get the warning "warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's complicated...

First of all, some compilers (see MikeCAT answer and Bill Lynch linked example) can compile the following code (if you give a name to the class and correct `lookup()` naming `n` the argument)

```
inline void func()
{
    double array[lookup(SIZE)];
}
```

because they support a C99 extension that accept the "variable length array" feature.

But this extension isn't standard C++.

You can verify this modifying `func()` as follows (almost equivalent, in standard C++)

```
inline void func()
{
    constexpr int s = lookup(SIZE);

    double array[s];
}
```

and this can't compile if `lookup()` is a non-static method

Consider that

```
 lookup(SIZE);
```

is a short form for

```
 this->lookup(SIZE);
```

I mean... the use of `lookup()` involve an object of your class.

The problem is that your `func()` method is available for both `constexpr` and non-`constexpr` objects.

Suppose you have a non-`constexpr` object: calling `func()` from it you impose that

```
constexpr int s = this->lookup(SIZE);
```

is evaluated compile-time.

That is: you impose that the `this` pointer (so the object itself) is available compile-time.

This is clearly impossible for run-time created objects, so your code can't compile.

Different if you declare `lookup()` as a `static` method: this way, calling `lookup()` doesn't involve an object of your class so your code can compile.

Comment: thanks for sifting through my typos to see what I was trying to ask!

Answer (score 0):

- Class template must have a name.
- `n` is not declared in `lookup`.

This should work as C++11:

```
template <int SIZE>
class hoge { // add hoge
   constexpr int lookup(const int n) const // add n
   {
      return n * n + n;
   }
   inline void func()
   {
       double array[lookup(SIZE)];
   }
};
```

Comment: Uhmmm... I don't think should works. If you add a `hoge<2> h; h.func()` (maybe declaring `func()` as `public:`) and compile with `-ansi -padantic` with clang++ or g++, you get a "warning: variable length arrays are a C99"  (clang++) or "warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array" (g++). If you add a row `constexpr int s = lookup(SIZE);` in `func()`, you get an error.

Comment: Ehmmm... sorry... in my preceding comment... `-pedantic`, not `-padantic`.